# Como asignar un certificado ssl a una ip de un Droplet en DigitalOcean?

Tags: nodejs, ssl, digitalocean

Tengo un certificado ssl de Let's Encrypt instalado en mi servidor nginx y funciona bien.

Y tengo mi app desarrollada con el MeanStack alojada en un droplet en DigitalOcean con un dominio que es jorgecastillodeveloper.pro. al entrar a http://jorgecastillodeveloper.pro el contenido carga bien pero cuando accedo a https://jorgecastillodeveloper.pro no me redirije a la aplicacion que tengo. Esta api esta corriendo en un puerto establesido por ejemplo 7777, he creado un regla de iptable para que aquello que entre por el puerto 80 me redirija al puerto 7777. pero esto solo lo hace cuando uso http://jorgecastillodeveloper.pro

Pueden acceder a http://jorgecastillodeveloper.pro y veran que el contenido carga bien pero cuando acceden a https://jorgecastillodeveloper.pro no lo carga porque me dice que hay problema de contenido mixto de https a http.

Ayuda porfavor...

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede cuando usas `https` el servidor está bloqueando las llamadas que haces a archivos externos si es que éstas no usan también `https`, de esta forma en tu sitio web si carga bootstrap:

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

pero no jquery:

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js
```

---

Lo que tienes que hacer es llamar a esos archivos mediante `https`, así

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js
```

o de otra forma llamar esas librerías localmente